# Synchronize two tables if the value doesnt exist at this moment

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two different tables with materialnumbers/partnumbers.

1. The first table looks like the following: string partnumber (primary key), string description
2. The second table looks like the following: int id (primary key), string partnumber, string description

The data is allready in the first table. The user could select some of the data from table one and this data should be created in table two if it doesnt exists.

My current code is the following but i think its inefficient:

```
if (this.SelectedMaterialNumbers != null)
{
            var allSelctedAnMatchingPartnumbers = db.Partnumbers.Where(x => x.Department.Id == user.Department.Id && this.SelectedMaterialNumbers.Contains(x.PartNumber)).ToList();

            foreach (var selectedPartnumberModel in allSelctedAnMatchingPartnumbers)
            {
                var relatedMaterialNumber = db.RelatedMaterialnumbers.Include(x => x.RelatedChangeRequests).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Department.Id == user.Department.Id && x.Materialnumber.Equals(selectedPartnumberModel.PartNumber));
                if(relatedMaterialNumber == null)
                {
                    db.RelatedMaterialnumbers.Add(new RelatedMaterialnumber { Department = user.Department, Materialnumber = selectedPartnumberModel.PartNumber, Description = selectedPartnumberModel.Description });
                }
                else
                {
                    relatedMaterialNumber.Description = selectedPartnumberModel.Description;
                    db.RelatedMaterialnumbers.Update(relatedMaterialNumber);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

Comment: How come you're storing the same data in two different tables ?

Comment: one database table is something like a master data (could change during time) and the other table is like a snapshot

Comment: Maybe Temporal tables or change tracking would suit you. With temporal tables SQL server remembers the time period where data was X, or Y; you can ask it "at jan 19, 2022 12:34:56.000123, what data was in this table for Id 123?" And it will tell you exactly what it was at that time. Latest EF core supports it too